# jQuery $("#form").submit not working in FF and Chrome (works OK in IE)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've seen this same problem discussed elsewhere, but none of the fixes I've found so far solve my paticular problem:

I'm using $.post inside $(#form).submit to submit the form via AJAX so the user doesn't leave the page.  It works just dandy in IE, but both FF and Chrome refresh the current page with the form field name and value in the querystring, probably because the form has no action="" specified.  I can get IE to duplicate the problem if I rename the function that is specified in , because then IE can't find the function to correctly perform the $.post and it also will refresh the current page with the form field name and value in the querystring.

The form is dynamically created, and needs to have the random number in the form name so that more than one form can be visible at a time.  I don't think that's part of the problem though, because the form name always shows up correctly in an alert() in all browsers.

```
function add_new_product(){

    var formName = "frm_add_new_product_" + window.random_number_for_IDs;

    alert('this alert is BEFORE the (#formname).submit');

    $("#" + formName).submit(function(event) {
        alert('this alert is inside the (#formname).submit BEFORE .preventDefault');
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('this alert is inside the (#formname).submit AFTER .preventDefault but BEFORE $.post');
        $.post("add_new_product.php?SiteID=<?php echo $_GET['SiteID']; ?>", $("#" + formName).serialize(), function(data){$("#DIV_new_product_name_" + window.random_number_for_IDs).html(data);});
        alert('this alert is inside the (#formname).submit AFTER $.post');
    });

    alert('this alert is AFTER the (#formname).submit');

    $("#DIV_new_product_form_" + window.random_number_for_IDs).fadeOut(100, function(){$("#DIV_new_product_name_" + window.random_number_for_IDs).fadeIn(100);});

}
```

In IE, I see all every alert() but not in the order specified above.  It first displays the ones before and after the $(#form).submit, and THEN the ones inside.  FF and Chrome only display the alerts() before and after the $(#form).submit, but never the ones inside.

Comment: What does the `<?php echo $_GET['SiteID']; ?>` display at the client? Is it what you expect? Also, the last "AFTER" alert will always display before those inside since the script only waits for the code inside the `function(data){}`. Anything you want done after the data has been returned to the client needs to go inside that `function(data){}`

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome's excellent built-in introspection tools, specifically the JavaScript debugger?  It only takes a second to set up: Ctrl+Shift+i, click Scripts, grab your script from the dropdown, and click the line numbers that you want to debug.

Comment: Niklas: Firebug shows that the SiteID from PHP is displayed properly. The mystery is why the .submit doesn't appear to be working at all.  If it did, the DIV I specified should be populated with the error from the target page at add_new_product.php

Comment: cheeken: I looked at the script in Chrome, but it appears to refresh the current page as described above before I can see anything useful in the debugger.  Perhaps I'm not using it correctly  :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

I changed the form's onSubmit from "add_new_product();" to "javascript:add_new_product();return false;" because preventDefault wasn't "prevent"ing the "default" action of the form submit.  That's why the page would just refresh with the field name and value in the querystring, because there was no "action" specified in the form tag and for whatever reason preventDefault was just not happening.  I also tried putting "return false;" inside the function after commenting out preventDefault  but it only works when it's in the  tag's onSubmit.

Then I commented out every line in the add_new_product() script except for the first line that concatenates the dynamic form name, the $.post line, and the last line that fades out the  and fades in the  that the ajax response populates via .html(data)

Works in all three browsers.